# How to tell if Java exception triggered while debugging in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, debugging, exception, intellij-idea

I'm stepping through some code with this kind of structure:

```
try {
  doSomething();
} finally {
  doAnotherThing();
  // more nested try statements down here
}
```

An exception is being triggered somewhere but I don't know if it's in `doSomething()`. Because the code goes to the `doAnotherThing()` regardless of whether an exception was triggered, that tells me nothing.

Is there a visual indication somewhere when an exception is triggered? (IntelliJ 14.1.7).

Comment: Just wondering: why again are you using a version of intellij that is like years old?

Comment: That's the version that I have a licence for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look under the Run -> Breakpoints menu item. You can add (using the '+' button), 'Java Exception Breakpoints' and specify the type of exception you want to break on. After it is added, you can use 'Disabled until selected breakpoint is hit' with another breakpoint inside your `try` block to restrict it to the code you care about. The [Breakpoints window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/breakpoints.html) contains a lot of useful controls for when the breakpoint is triggered.

If you need to know if an exception was thrown, it will need to be stored in code:

```
Throwable thrown = null; 
try {   
    //Do very important work here
} catch (ImportantException e) {
    thrown = e;
    throw e;
} finally {   
    if (thrown != null) {
        //We arrived in the finally block due to an exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. Is there a direct way to see "there is currently an exception being handled."

Comment: Unfortunately no. The closest you will get is following the methods listed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184704/is-it-possible-to-detect-if-an-exception-occurred-before-i-entered-a-finally-blo