# Java know in finally that exception thrown without any variable

Tags: java, exception, try-catch-finally, try-finally

Is there a way to know in `finally` that exception is thrown,  without using any extra variable as below:

```
 boolean hasFailed = true;
 try { // code

     //...
     hasFailed = false;
  } finally {
      if (hasFailed) {
         // handle failure
      }
   }
```

Similarly, also without adding exception variable (using `catch` clause), 
I didn't find [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184704/is-it-possible-to-detect-if-an-exception-occurred-before-i-entered-a-finally-blo) in similar questions

Comment: No; use a `catch` block.

Comment: @SLaks also with catch block, how to not use extra variable?

Comment: @Lorelorelore there is not such option in answers

Comment: @user7294900: what is the issue with having 1 "extra" boolean flag? Just use the normal `try`/`catch` flow and set the flag to `true` in the catch block. I would also suggest logging the error in non-trivial code.

Comment: @derekmckinnon can't finally block know exception is thrown?

Comment: @user7294900 No. That's not how the language was designed.

Comment: @derekmckinnon there is unhandled exception handler as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588634/is-there-an-unhandled-exception-handler-in-java

Comment: An `UncaughtExceptionHandler` is only called when the `Thread` is about to _terminate_ because no other code caught the exception.

Comment: @user7294900 You should just use the language as it was intended instead of trying to make it work the way you think it should. As slaw mentioned, the mechanism you are referring to is not meant for this and is a hack. Anyone maintaining code after you will hate their existence if you do this...trust me