# Java. What is the valid way try to close all connections?

Tags: java, error-handling, io, try-catch, ioexception

For example, I have method for working with input/output streams:

```
    public void doSomethingWithStreams () throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
            {
             OutputStream out1, out2;            
             InputStream in1, in2;
try{                     
            //do something with Streams: read, write, process, etc.
            }
finally{
        //There I try to close connections
        out1.close();
        out2.close();
        in1.close();
        in2.close();
        }    
            }
```

Method can throws IOException and it is valid behavior.
But If I have Exception in this line:

```
 out1.close();
```

others three Stream will be **NOT** closed.
What solution can you recommend? How? How close **all**?

I have just one:

```
    public void doSomethingWithStreams () throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
            {
             OutputStream out1, out2;            
             InputStream in1, in2;
         try{            
            //do something with Streams: read, write, process, etc.
            }
finally{
        //There I try to close connections

try{out1.close();}
  finally{
     try{out2.close();}
         finally{
            try{in1.close();}
                finally{
        in2.close();}
}}

}

            }
```

As you can see - my approach is using multiple try-finally blocks.

Do you think it is good idea?

Comment: This could be of your interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224658/java-try-finally-block-to-close-stream

Comment: Please can you be a good citizen and learn how to format your code and then fix the formatting in this question. I almost closed this question due to how hard it is to read. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If three streams are not dependent on each other, may be having try/catch for each stream look cleaner.

Something like:

```
try{
 out1.close();
}catch(Exception e)
{
....
}finally
```

{....
}

```
try{
        out2.close();
}catch(Exception e)
{
.....
}finally
```

{....
}

EDIT: As iccthedral suggested, if you use Java7 you may use [try-with-resource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) block.

Comment: Or even better with Java7 try-with-resource block.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best way to go about it is:

```
try (
     OutputStream out1 = ...;
     OutputStream out2 = ...;
     InputStream in1 = ...;
     InputStream in2 = ...;
) {
     ...
}
```

Comment: Maybe worth noting it requires 1.7+

Comment: @assylias End of public for 1.6 has been pushed back to February 2013. You really don't want to be working on new code for something with a lifetime that short. 1.7 is the norm.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the best way to clean this up is to make a method like this:

```
public static void close(Closeable c) {
   if (c == null) return; 
   try {
       c.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       // Do anything or nothing
   }
}
```

This can replace your .close() calls and won't throw exceptions if they fail.

Comment: This is a good solution.

Comment: @Chris, solution with catch(IOException ex){//Do nothing} is Wrong Solution! It is my opinion.

Comment: @user471011 Yeah, you probably shouldn't be ignoring exceptions. In a serious project you should at the very least be logging them. That's why I left the `Do anything OR nothing` comment there; its up to the reader to decide what needs to be done when a stream fails to close.