# Strange behavior with try-catch on Dynamics Ax 2012

Tags: try-catch, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm trying without success to figure out what I'm doing wrong trying to handle one exception in my code, hopefully someone can help me.

I'm reading an external database from within Ax to integrate some customers. So I loop through a series of records using a ResultSet object. at a given point I have some code that looks like this:

```
while (resultSet.next())
{
    //some logic (...)

    ttsbegin;

    //This is a custom table that stores to where I want to integrate the given customer
    while select integrationCompany
            where integrationCompany.CRMCompany == customerInfo.parmCRMDataAreaId()
    {
        changeCompany(integrationCompany.ERPCompany)
        {
            try
            {
                customerInfo.createCustomer();

                //.. some more logic


            }
            catch
            {
                // My catch Block, that should update the source database to set
                // the processing status to "error"


                ttsAbort;
            }
        }
    }

    ttsCommit;

}
```

And inside the customerInfo.createCustomer() method I'm explicitly throwing some exceptions (throw Exception::Error) if some requirements aren't met.

The problem is that the catch block isn't reached - the program stops without getting back to the main routine.

Does it has something to do with the transaction opening/aborting/commiting or is something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AX (*X++*) is strange here (if you are used .NET/Java like try/catch scenario).

If you have try inside the transaction, then fist catch cathes the excation (which is *Enum* and not sort of exception object).

From the MSDN: [Exceptions Inside Transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa893385.aspx):

> When an exception is thrown inside a ttsBegin - ttsCommit transaction block, no catch statement inside that transaction block can process the exception. Instead, the innermost catch statements that are outside the transaction block are the first catch statements to be tested.

Comment: See also [Sample 5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa893385.aspx#Sample5)

Comment: Totally right! Thanks a lot, I worked out the order of try-catch vs transactions and it worked just fine!

Comment: I found this blog post useful for more examples and information on exception handling: http://daxmusings.codecrib.com/2013/04/exception-handling-in-dynamics-ax.html

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535992/how-to-catch-inner-exception