# Try/Catch does not work on conversion error, while importing data from excel in X++

Tags: try-catch, axapta, x++

I am trying to import data from excel to my journal, but if there is a conversion error, it just blocks my journal. I want to make try/catch exception, but it does not work.

My code looks like this:

```
try
{
    [My insert code]
}
catch (Exception::Error)
{                    
    throw error("error here");
}
```

Error looks like this:

> Error executing code: Wrong type of argument for conversion function.

And first suggestion probably will be "Fix the conversion code", but it wouldnt resolve my problem...
Does anyone know why my catch block does not see that error?
I tried to find exception for conversion errors, but there is like 0 information about it on internet.

Comment: Try removing `(Exception::Error)` and leaving only `catch`. That will help you rule out different error types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try without this `(Exception::Error)`  because it is probably that your code does not give an Error exception.

```
try
{
    [My insert code]
}
catch
{                    
    throw error("error here");
}
```

Comment: Yes, this solution worked. I dont know if this is optimal solution, but it works. Atleast now its not blocking my journal on error. All i had to do was - remove the exception

Answer (score 2):

There are only two possible reasons why your `catch` does not work:

1. The conversion code does not throw an Error exception.
   It might throw a CILError or something else.
2. You have a `ttsBegin` / `ttsCommit` outside of your `try` / `catch`.
   Exceptions inside a transaction [cannot be caught](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12535992/4509) (for good reasons).

Comment: ttsbegin and ttscommit is inside the try/catch block...

Comment: Then 1. was the correct answer in your case.